# run jenkins parallel job and wait from different servers

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, command, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement of Build and deployment using Jenkins. But i need to design for this  work flow.

```
JOB 1 (primary build from A server)
 |------> JOB A (deploy)
 |------> JOB B (deploy)

JOB 2 (delta build from B server)
 |------> JOB C (deploy)
 |------> JOB D (deploy)

Job 3 (this should execute upon JOBS A B C D are successful).
```

JOB 1 and Job 2 are configured in 2 servers as the build generates in 2 servers. I have a JOB which can do both the JOBS 1 & 2, how can we achive the execution of JOB 3.

Any Ideas ?

or can it be configured like this

```
JOB Main-- |
           |--->JOB 1 (primary build from A server)
                  |------> JOB A (deploy)
                  |------> JOB B (deploy)

           |--->JOB 2 (delta build from B server)
                  |------> JOB C (deploy)
                  |------> JOB D (deploy)
           |---> JOB 3 (upon completing the JOB 1,2 and JOB A B C D)
```

Screen shots would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this a simple way to doing without using any specific plugin.

You can have your jobs create a particular file on completion of execution like

JobA_Success.txt,

JobB_Success.txt,

JobC_Success.txt and

JobD_Success.txt

```
Job Main

  |    
   --> Job 1 (Job A and Job B) triggers Job 3 after execution

   --> Job 2 (Job C and Job D) triggers Job 3 after execution


Job 3 --> Uses a script trigger which will check for all the 4 text files to be present and only if present it will start building otherwise there is no new build.
```

This is just a logical thought, hope it is useful